# How to index Multilist with lucene

Tags: .net, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

In our template we defined a Multilist field. We added this field to the Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config file:

```
<field fieldName="apps_or"                storageType="YES"  indexType="TOKENIZED"    vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.GUID" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
```

Why is this necessary when it says `<IndexAllFields>true</IndexAllFields>` in this file anyway?

After we added this line and published all content we see the field appearing in the Overview tab of the Luke tool. But in the Documents tab the field is still missing. Also when we do a Content search on the web index using .Net the field is always null:

```
class NewsSearchResultItem : SearchResultItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Introduction { get; set; }

    [IndexField("apps_or")]
    public IEnumerable<ID> AppIdOr { get; set; }

}
```

apps_or is the name of the index as it appears in the Luke tool. Any ideas how to properly  get the field in the index and have it available through .Net??

Many thanks in advance
Robert

Comment: Can you try to use List<ID> not IEnumerable<ID>, I'm not 100% sure it will work, I remember I see this problem before...

Comment: Same behavior unfortunately. One would expect an exception when types are wrong? is there maybe a log file that contains this kind of info after a search?

Comment: The behavior you describe is typical of a field that is indexed, but not stored, in Lucene.  I don't know enough about Sitecore to see any issues with what you have there, though.  `storageType="YES"` sounds correct to me, but it still appears to be unstored.  Hope that points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You are right femtoRgon! It was indexed but not stored, apparently you have to enable storing multilist fields in the same config file:

```
<fieldType fieldTypeName="multilist"                          storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="NO" boost="1f" type="System.String"   settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" />
```